# GitLab behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I have problems getting GitLab to work behind an nginx reverse proxy.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

gitlab-ce                             11.3.6-ce.0
```

in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb I have set (according to documentation):

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.mydomain.io'
nginx['listen_port'] = 81
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

I used port 81 so the reverse proxy can bind to 80 so it's easier to get LetsEncrypt certificates. This is my virtual host for the gitlab subdomain:

```
 upstream gitlab {
server localhost:81 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 82;
    listen [::]:82;
    server_name gitlab.mydomain.io;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name gitlab.mydomain.io;

ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.io.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.io.key;

 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

  location / {
            proxy_read_timeout      300;
            proxy_connect_timeout   300;
            proxy_redirect          off;

  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header        Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;
            proxy_pass              https://gitlab;
    }
```

}

When I navigate to my subdomain, I get a 502 Bad Gateway with the following error in the nginx log:

```
 [error] 6301#6301: *6 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 88.217.180.123, server: gitlab.mydomain.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:81/", host: "gitlab.mydomain.io"
```

I tried using different protocols with nginx but to no avail. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't think this is a programic problem. You may find help on unix.stackexchange.com or similar. And to the problem, does your gitlab also hosts on https? So there are two instances of certificates - one for gitlab, and the other for nginx proxy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ServerFault or Unix.SE ...